# Cannot use tensorflow-upstream as XLA for JAX customized installation on AMD GPU

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, jax

I followed the JAX installation tutorial here: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html#additional-notes-for-building-a-rocm-jaxlib-for-amd-gpus

After I git clone the tensorflow-upstream as the XLA for JAX from ROCM repository (https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream.git) and install with the following command

```
python3 build/build.py --enable_rocm --rocm_path=/opt/rocm-5.4.3 --bazel_options=--override_repository=xla=/home/aac/jax/tensorflow-upstream
```

it gives me the following error messages:

```
  _   _  __  __
    | | / \ \ \/ /
 _  | |/ _ \ \  /
| |_| / ___ \/  \
 \___/_/   \/_/\_\


Bazel binary path: ./bazel-6.1.2-linux-x86_64
Bazel version: 6.1.2
Python binary path: /usr/bin/python3
Python version: 3.9
NumPy version: 1.26.0
MKL-DNN enabled: yes
Target CPU: x86_64
Target CPU features: release
CUDA enabled: no
TPU enabled: no
ROCm enabled: yes
ROCm toolkit path: /opt/rocm-5.4.3
ROCm amdgpu targets: gfx900,gfx906,gfx908,gfx90a,gfx1030

Building XLA and installing it in the jaxlib source tree...
./bazel-6.1.2-linux-x86_64 run --verbose_failures=true //jaxlib/tools:build_wheel -- --output_path=/home/aac/jax/dist --cpu=x86_64
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=80
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --nocheck_visibility --apple_platform_type=macos --macos_minimum_os=10.14 --announce_rc --define open_source_build=true --spawn_strategy=standalone --enable_platform_specific_config --experimental_cc_shared_library --define=no_aws_support=true --define=no_gcp_support=true --define=no_hdfs_support=true --define=no_kafka_support=true --define=no_ignite_support=true --define=grpc_no_ares=true --define=tsl_link_protobuf=true -c opt --config=short_logs --copt=-DMLIR_PYTHON_PACKAGE_PREFIX=jaxlib.mlir. --@xla//xla/python:enable_gpu=false
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /home/aac/jax/.jax_configure.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --strategy=Genrule=standalone --repo_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 --action_env=PYENV_ROOT --python_path=/usr/bin/python3 --action_env ROCM_PATH=/opt/rocm-5.4.3 --override_repository=xla=/home/aac/jax/tensorflow-upstream --config=avx_posix --config=mkl_open_source_only --config=rocm
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:avx_posix in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --copt=-mavx --host_copt=-mavx
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:mkl_open_source_only in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --define=tensorflow_mkldnn_contraction_kernel=1
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:rocm in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --crosstool_top=@local_config_rocm//crosstool:toolchain --define=using_rocm=true --define=using_rocm_hipcc=true --@xla//xla/python:enable_gpu=true --define=xla_python_enable_gpu=true --repo_env TF_NEED_ROCM=1 --action_env TF_ROCM_AMDGPU_TARGETS=gfx900,gfx906,gfx908,gfx90a,gfx1030
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:rocm in file /home/aac/jax/.jax_configure.bazelrc: --action_env TF_ROCM_AMDGPU_TARGETS=gfx900,gfx906,gfx908,gfx90a,gfx1030
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:linux in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --config=posix --copt=-Wno-unknown-warning-option --copt=-Wno-stringop-truncation --copt=-Wno-array-parameter
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:posix in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --copt=-fvisibility=hidden --copt=-Wno-sign-compare --cxxopt=-std=c++17 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++17
Loading: 
ERROR: Error computing the main repository mapping: cannot load '@xla//:workspace4.bzl': no such file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aac/jax/build/build.py", line 598, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/aac/jax/build/build.py", line 580, in main
    shell(command)
  File "/home/aac/jax/build/build.py", line 44, in shell
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./bazel-6.1.2-linux-x86_64', 'run', '--verbose_failures=true', '//jaxlib/tools:build_wheel', '--', '--output_path=/home/aac/jax/dist', '--cpu=x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

How to solve this?

I tried to use the JAX default XLA with the following command

```
python3 build/build.py --enable_rocm --rocm_path=/opt/rocm-5.4.3
```

It gave the following error message:

```
   _   _  __  __
    | | / \ \ \/ /
 _  | |/ _ \ \  /
| |_| / ___ \/  \
 \___/_/   \/_/\_\


Bazel binary path: ./bazel-6.1.2-linux-x86_64
Bazel version: 6.1.2
Python binary path: /usr/bin/python3
Python version: 3.9
NumPy version: 1.26.0
MKL-DNN enabled: yes
Target CPU: x86_64
Target CPU features: release
CUDA enabled: no
TPU enabled: no
ROCm enabled: yes
ROCm toolkit path: /opt/rocm-5.4.3
ROCm amdgpu targets: gfx900,gfx906,gfx908,gfx90a,gfx1030

Building XLA and installing it in the jaxlib source tree...
./bazel-6.1.2-linux-x86_64 run --verbose_failures=true //jaxlib/tools:build_wheel -- --output_path=/home/aac/jax/dist --cpu=x86_64
INFO: Options provided by the client:
  Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=0 --terminal_columns=80
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'common' options: --experimental_repo_remote_exec
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --nocheck_visibility --apple_platform_type=macos --macos_minimum_os=10.14 --announce_rc --define open_source_build=true --spawn_strategy=standalone --enable_platform_specific_config --experimental_cc_shared_library --define=no_aws_support=true --define=no_gcp_support=true --define=no_hdfs_support=true --define=no_kafka_support=true --define=no_ignite_support=true --define=grpc_no_ares=true --define=tsl_link_protobuf=true -c opt --config=short_logs --copt=-DMLIR_PYTHON_PACKAGE_PREFIX=jaxlib.mlir. --@xla//xla/python:enable_gpu=false
INFO: Reading rc options for 'run' from /home/aac/jax/.jax_configure.bazelrc:
  Inherited 'build' options: --strategy=Genrule=standalone --repo_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python3 --action_env=PYENV_ROOT --python_path=/usr/bin/python3 --action_env ROCM_PATH=/opt/rocm-5.4.3 --config=avx_posix --config=mkl_open_source_only --config=rocm
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:short_logs in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --output_filter=DONT_MATCH_ANYTHING
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:avx_posix in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --copt=-mavx --host_copt=-mavx
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:mkl_open_source_only in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --define=tensorflow_mkldnn_contraction_kernel=1
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:rocm in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --crosstool_top=@local_config_rocm//crosstool:toolchain --define=using_rocm=true --define=using_rocm_hipcc=true --@xla//xla/python:enable_gpu=true --define=xla_python_enable_gpu=true --repo_env TF_NEED_ROCM=1 --action_env TF_ROCM_AMDGPU_TARGETS=gfx900,gfx906,gfx908,gfx90a,gfx1030
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:rocm in file /home/aac/jax/.jax_configure.bazelrc: --action_env TF_ROCM_AMDGPU_TARGETS=gfx900,gfx906,gfx908,gfx90a,gfx1030
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:linux in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --config=posix --copt=-Wno-unknown-warning-option --copt=-Wno-stringop-truncation --copt=-Wno-array-parameter
INFO: Found applicable config definition build:posix in file /home/aac/jax/.bazelrc: --copt=-fvisibility=hidden --copt=-Wno-sign-compare --cxxopt=-std=c++17 --host_cxxopt=-std=c++17
Loading: 
DEBUG: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/xla/third_party/repo.bzl:132:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'tf_runtime' because it already exists.
DEBUG: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/xla/third_party/repo.bzl:132:14: 
Warning: skipping import of repository 'llvm-raw' because it already exists.
Loading: 
Loading: 1 packages loaded
Analyzing: target //jaxlib/tools:build_wheel (2 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/local_config_python/BUILD:78:8: in outs attribute of genrule rule @local_config_python//:python_include: Genrules without outputs don't make sense
ERROR: /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/local_config_python/BUILD:78:8: Analysis of target '@local_config_python//:python_include' failed
INFO: Repository ml_dtypes instantiated at:
  /home/aac/jax/WORKSPACE:15:15: in <toplevel>
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/xla/workspace2.bzl:90:19: in workspace
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/workspace2.bzl:627:28: in workspace
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/workspace2.bzl:53:14: in _initialize_third_party
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/third_party/py/ml_dtypes/workspace.bzl:12:20: in repo
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/third_party/repo.bzl:136:21: in tf_http_archive
Repository rule _tf_http_archive defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/third_party/repo.bzl:89:35: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository com_google_absl instantiated at:
  /home/aac/jax/WORKSPACE:15:15: in <toplevel>
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/xla/workspace2.bzl:90:19: in workspace
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/workspace2.bzl:627:28: in workspace
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/workspace2.bzl:45:9: in _initialize_third_party
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/third_party/absl/workspace.bzl:39:20: in repo
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/third_party/repo.bzl:136:21: in tf_http_archive
Repository rule _tf_http_archive defined at:
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/17cfb08ca12f3651a79f2404cf808c7c/external/tsl/third_party/repo.bzl:89:35: in <toplevel>
INFO: Repository nanobind instantiated at:
  /home/aac/jax/WORKSPACE:30:9: in <toplevel>
  /home/aac/jax/third_party/nanobind/workspace.bzl:20:20: in repo
  /home/aac/jax/third_party/repo.bzl:142:21: in tf_http_archive
Repository rule _tf_http_archive defined at:
  /home/aac/jax/third_party/repo.bzl:89:35: in <toplevel>
ERROR: Analysis of target '//jaxlib/tools:build_wheel' failed; build aborted: 
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.849s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (67 packages loaded, 484 targets configured)
ERROR: Build failed. Not running target
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aac/jax/build/build.py", line 598, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/aac/jax/build/build.py", line 580, in main
    shell(command)
  File "/home/aac/jax/build/build.py", line 44, in shell
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['./bazel-6.1.2-linux-x86_64', 'run', '--verbose_failures=true', '//jaxlib/tools:build_wheel', '--', '--output_path=/home/aac/jax/dist', '--cpu=x86_64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the ROCM instructions on that documentation page are out-of-date: the build now depends on OpenXLA rather than extracting the XLA sources from tensorflow. [google/jax#17910](https://github.com/google/jax/pull/17910) updates these instructions.